# Centering Barplot's Y-axis values around 0

Tags: r, ggplot2

So Im trying to create a Barplot of % change in counts of homelessness between two years for all States.

```
   X1     X2
1  AK -0.025
2  AL  0.031
3  AR -0.135
4  AZ  0.187
5  CA -0.041
6  CO  0.106
7  CT  0.004
8  DC  0.046
9  DE  0.023
10 FL  0.013
11 GA  0.004
12 GU  0.208
13 HI -0.006
14 IA   0.01
15 ID -0.049
16 IL  0.059
17 IN  0.051
18 KS   0.07
19 KY  0.043
20 LA  0.136
21 MA -0.126
22 MD -0.021
23 ME   0.06
24 MI   0.03
25 MN  0.082
26 MO  0.087
27 MS  0.073
28 MT  0.092
29 NC  0.041
30 ND -0.031
31 NE  0.159
32 NH  0.021
33 NJ -0.023
34 NM  0.021
35 NV  0.159
36 NY -0.093
37 OH  0.047
38 OK   0.02
39 OR  0.127
40 PA -0.014
41 PR -0.071
42 RI  0.073
43 SC -0.075
44 SD  0.197
45 TN -0.027
46 TX  0.078
47 UT -0.007
48 VA  0.032
49 VI -0.008
50 VT  0.152
51 WA  0.028
52 WI  -0.03
53 WV  0.083
54 WY -0.045

ggplot(data = prcnt_diff_state_hmlsns, 
              aes(x=prcnt_diff_state_hmlsns$X1,y=prcnt_diff_state_hmlsns$X2)) +
       geom_bar(stat = "identity",color="blue",fill="steelblue",width = .6) + 
       scale_y_discrete(name = "Percent Change in Homelessness") +
       scale_x_discrete(name = "State")
```

the data im using is a 2 column dataframe with each state and their percent change in homelessness between 2014 and 2015. Obviously, the resulting output is pretty bad. My intent was to have the graph's y axis to be centered around 0, to better show the difference between each state. Instead though, the axis starts at the lowest value and goes to the highest, not making much sense in terms of interpretation.

How exactly do I go about changing the graph's axis to that the values are centered around 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplifying your code, using `geom_col` instead of `geom_bar`, and sorting the x-axis:

```
ggplot(data = prcnt_diff_state_hmlsns,
       aes(x = reorder(X1, X2), y = X2)) +
  geom_col(fill = "steelblue", width = .6) +
  labs(x = "State", y = "Percent Change in Homelessness")
```

[image]

(I guess I had a different default theme set too.)

A few pointers: **never** use `data$column` inside `aes()`, just use unquoted column names. For anything area-based, use `fill` not `color`. And I like the `labs()` function for labeling axes and scales.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. Unfortunately, I am actually getting the exact same result in my original post.

Comment: Then... somehow the code from my answer must not have run. Was there an error? A warning? OR, maybe there's a data issue? Is your `X2` column numeric? What is `str(prcnt_diff_state_hmlsns)`?

Comment: Yes! Thank you for catching then. I had to first change prcnt_diff_state_hmlsns into a data.frame and apparently values in X2 became a string not a numeric. I changed the values to numeric and now I have the correct plot. Thank!